# Firebase database rule $id doesnt work

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Currently I'm a little bit confused, because my rule doesn't work as I though it would...

my structure:

```
{
  "news" : {
    "firstNew" : {
      "comments" : {
        "firstComment" : {
          "date" : "2017.03.22.",
          "text" : "első comment!",
          "user" : {
            "email" : "user1@gmail.com",
            "uid" : "blabla"
          }
        },
        "secondComment" : {
          "text" : "second comment",
          "user" : {
            "email" : "alma@beka.com",
            "uid" : "alma"
          }
        }
      },
      "content" : {
        "text" : "Itt sok sok sok sok sok sok sok sok szöveg lesz, nagyon sok szöveg meg mindenféle",
        "title" : "Az első hír az oldalon"
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "user1" : {
      "email" : "blabla@gmail.com",
      "roles" : {
        "administrator" : true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "news":{
        ".read": true,
            "content":{
            ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('roles').child('administrator').val() === true"
          },
         "comments":{
           "$comment": {
                    ".write": true
            }
         }
      }
  }
}
```

I just can't write the comments! I'm trying to simulate it, with authentication, and using the good 'uid'. 
I'm trying this: news/firstNew/comments/secondComment
with uid: alma

please help me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: additional information: ofc I won't use it like this, I will check the auth.uid in the $comment/.write, it is just a test context, but even this doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed a level of my structure in the rule..